# Quickest way to check if a number is in a set?

Tags: javascript, list, hash, numbers, find

What is the fastest method to check if a number is in a list in Javascript?

I know about indexOf >= but it seems rather slow to me.

I have to perform millions of checks per second and the list is rather short (max ~10 entries)

Comment: An O(n) search through 10 items may actually be _faster_ than a constant-time lookup, due to the difference in baseline overhead.

Comment: Millions of checks per second? Really?

Comment: Are all checks against the same list?

Comment: How large is the range of values?

Comment: If the data does not change frequently, you can sort, then use binary search on them. That is if actually you have millions of records. Because of @MattBall's reason. Otherwise use an object instead (a dictionary or hash table in other languages)

Comment: In 2021, one should use [`new Set([ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 ]).has(7)`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Answer (score 2):

Try it out at [jsperf](http://jsperf.com) but I suspect that using an object and setting up the numbers as properties would be faster than an array search.

```
var theList = { 1: true, 2000: true, 253: true, -12077: true, ... };

if (theList[ someNumber ]) { // see if some number is in the list
```

Now, that said, you're not going to be able to do anything useful in JavaScript in a web browser millions of times per second, except perhaps on extremely high-end machines that aren't doing much else.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is better to use `indexof()`

As an alternative which is not appreciated in your case is to use `Enumerable#include`

You can use [Enumerable#include](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Enumerable/prototype/include/) but I doubt if it is faster than `indexof()` Something like:-

```
[1, 2, '3', '4', '5'].include(3);
```

Comment: You're suggesting he load the prototypejs library for this? And that it'll be the fastest solution?

Comment: I have just given him an another alternative. I have mentioned that it is not faster but OP doesnot want to use indexof().

Comment: Well that's the reason for the -1. OP isn't looking for random alternatives, and it would be silly to include a large library for a single method that does basically the same thing as he's currently doing.

Comment: Yes I fully agree that including a libarary is a bad idea. But then in that case OP doesnot have a choice other than IndexOf() ;)

Comment: @RahulTripathi that's not really true, however; there is at least one other choice.

Comment: A `for` loop or an object property lookup are likely much faster.

Comment: @Pointy:- Seen your answer Sir. Thats a good one. But are we really sure that this is the structure of list which OP has?

Comment: @RahulTripathi no, but conversion of a short (remember, not more than ten items) list in an array to a list as an object is trivial.

Comment: @CrazyTrain:- Fully agree. But I still think that using IndexOf() would be a better idea. Kindly correct me if I am wrong. P.S:- Updated my answer as well!!! :)

Comment: @Pointy:- Agreed. +1 :)

Comment: If OP really needs this lookup millions of times per second *(which sounds a little suspicious IMO)*, then he's going to need every bit of optimization that can be found. In such a case, one often needs to trade short code for optimized code. I don't think any of us really knows enough about the actual situation to offer the best solution.

Comment: @CrazyTrain:- Millions of times per second is really questionable!! ;) P.S. Do you really think that still I deserve a downvote? :(

Comment: Yes, you've not provided a reasonable solution that would improve performance over `.indexOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for speed of comprehension, use [`array.includes`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/includes):

```js
[-1, 1, 2].includes(0)  // false
[-1, 1, 2].includes(-1) // true
[-1, 1, 2].includes(-2) // false
[-1, 1, 2].includes(2)  // true
[-1, 1, 2].includes(3)  // false
```